# Locust 95 percentile is higher than max

Tags: locust

Sometimes when I run locust for some scenarios 95 percentile value is  more than max. As far as I understood 95 percentile means the 95% of requests took lesser time than this.So how can Max value be lesser than 95 percentile? I am I doing something wrong here.

I also found that this only happens when there very less number of requests like 15 or less.

Answer (score 3):

Percentiles are approximated in Locust.

This is done for performance reasons, as calculating an exact percentile would need to consider every sample (and doing this continously for large runs would just not work)

Min, max and average (mean) are accurate though.

And in longer runs (more than those 15 requests) the 95th percentile should not exceed your max.