# What is Aggregated value for percentile columns in Locust report?

Tags: load-testing, locust, percentile

Please clarify how Aggregated value for percentile columns is calculated?

So I have csv results opened in Excel. Values in yellow box are not average, are not median, are not 90%ile... I've no idea what are they.

[image]

*(I've hidden most of lines to fit screen, so selected aggregated values are incorrect for what you see per column)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are exactly what they claim to be, the percentiles for all requests made.

But because calculating percentiles is computationally hard, they are approximated. Also see [Locust 95 percentile is higher than max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66705025/locust-95-percentile-is-higher-than-max)